# Scanner of HP Laserjet Pro MFP m177fw incompatible with Big Sur

Tags: big-sur, scanning

I can install the HP Laserjet Pro MFP m177fw on macOS Mojave with the default installation (just click `+` on `Printers and Scanners` and follow the steps). Then I see `Print` and `Scan` tabs, and an `Open Scanner` button.

I can install the same printer on macOS Big Sur and print sheets. But the `Scan` tab is not there. This happens whether I install via USB cable or wi-fi.

I also installed HP EasyScan drivers and am unable to use the scanner.

I suspect it is some incompatibility between Big Sur and HP's scanners. Given the long time Big Sur has been around, I suspect someone has had the same issue and found a workaround.

How can I install the HP scanner on Big Sur?

Comment: I can confirm HP Easy Scan works for an M477 on Big Sur. We installed the new Easy Start, but the older migrated app was fine [modified date shows 2016, Mac is M1 from April this year], so we left it where it was.

Comment: Have you try with this : https://support.apple.com/guide/image-capture/scan-images-imgcp1004/mac ? Else, you can try with the test version of VueScan : https://www.hamrick.com